# QML TableView refresh in realtime only updates UI every 1 second

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a task of showing big amount of data in realtime (as close to that as possible) with UI update every 10 to 100ms (best to worst values), I've managed to create a test model generating random numbers and populating the table view with new set of random values with a Timer. I tried to set different time intervals from 1 to 100 ms, and I can see the timer fires and the new set of data is created, but the UI updates strictly in 1 second every time despite the timer interval value.
Can you guide me on how to handle UI updates in less than 1 second.

I tried different amount of data from tables of 50x1000 to just 50x50. Every time I get UI update rate of 1 second.

It is based on the "Game Of Life" Qt example, so some of the elements are just not used and are obsolete, but as soon as they are "disabled" I think they don't make any influence on the rest of the code and the problem itself.
You can see that in nextStep() method I invoke timestamp logging to console and I can see in the output that the method is invoked according to the timer, but the UI only updates visually every second.

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: root
visible: true
width: 760
height: 810
minimumWidth: 475
minimumHeight: 300

color: "#09102B"
title: qsTr("Conway’s Game of Life")

//! [tableview]
TableView {
    id: tableView
    anchors.fill: parent

    rowSpacing: 1
    columnSpacing: 1

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {}
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}

    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: cell
        implicitWidth: 45
        implicitHeight: 15

        color: model.value > 100 ? "#f3f3f4" : "#b5b7bf"
        Label {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            text: model.value
        }
    }
    //! [tableview]

    //! [model]
    model: GameOfLifeModel {
        id: gameOfLifeModel
    }
    //! [model]

    //! [scroll]
    contentX: 0;
    contentY: 0;
    //! [scroll]
}

footer: Rectangle {
    signal nextStep

    id: footer
    height: 50
    color: "#F3F3F4"

    RowLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        //! [next]
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Next")
            onClicked: gameOfLifeModel.nextStep()
        }
        //! [next]

        Item {
            width: 50
        }

        Button {
            text: timer.running ? "❙❙" : "▶️"
            onClicked: timer.running = !timer.running
        }
    }

    FpsItem {
            id: fpsItem
            anchors.left: parent
            color: "black"
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 10
        running: true
        repeat: true

        onTriggered: gameOfLifeModel.nextStep()
    }
}
```

}

gameoflifemodel.cpp

```
GameOfLifeModel::GameOfLifeModel(QObject *parent)
: QAbstractTableModel(parent) {}
//! [modelsize]
int GameOfLifeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;

    return height;
}
int GameOfLifeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;

    return width;
}
//! [modelsize]

//! [read]
QVariant GameOfLifeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || role != CellRole)
        return QVariant();

    return m_state[index.column()][index.row()];
}
//! [read]

//! [write / not used]
bool GameOfLifeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    if (role != CellRole || data(index, role) == value)
        return false;

    m_state[index.column()][index.row()] = value.toBool();
    emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});

    return true;
}
//! [write]

Qt::ItemFlags GameOfLifeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

//! [update]
void GameOfLifeModel::nextStep()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss,zzz");

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            m_state[j][i] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
        }
    }

    emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(height - 1, width - 1), {CellRole});
}
//! [update]
```

gameoflifemodel.h

```
//! [modelclass]
class GameOfLifeModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_ENUMS(Roles)
public:
    enum Roles {
        CellRole
    };

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
        return {
            { CellRole, "value" }
        };
    }

    explicit GameOfLifeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
             int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    Q_INVOKABLE void nextStep();

private:
    static constexpr int width = 50;
    static constexpr int height = 50;
    static constexpr int size = width * height;

    template <class T, size_t ROW, size_t COL>
    using NativeMatrix = T[ROW][COL];
    NativeMatrix<int, height, width> m_state;
};
//! [modelclass]
```

Comment: Hmm ... as for me `TableView` too redundant for your purposes. I would base that on a custom item. Refresh all the table, model every 10 ms it is overloading.

Comment: Do you have something in your code that blocks the event loop and only returns to it once per second? If you don't return to the event loop, drawing is blocked.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm refreshing the whole table - only visible rows if I'm not missing something in the architecture. But still if it is 50x50 it should be fine to update it within 10 ms.
I don't see anything that blocks the event loop. But I might be missing something. Can you direct me where to check for those blocks? Or how should I return to the event loop explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved. The issue appeared to be in the random number generation process, not in the table view.
In the code I used

```
srand(time(NULL))
```

The time(NULL) returns seconds and not milliseconds, thus I was getting the same numbers and they were updated only after 1 second and visually it was similar to updating the UI only every second. In order to solve this I switched to using this to generate random numbers and everything worked well:

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

/* using nano-seconds instead of seconds */
srand((time_t)ts.tv_nsec);
```